# Deeptools cannot find file that exists

Tags: python, io, pysam

An intern of mine is trying to use deeptools' bamCoverage function, and it throws a `'/my/dir/data.bam' file does not exist` error, despite the file being there. Yes, the file does exist, we can manipulate it using bash commands just fine so there's no real reason for it to throw that error.

According to [this thread](https://github.com/deeptools/deepTools/issues/663), it could be an issue with pysam or python. Both are fully up to date. Do you know how I could investigate issues with pysam or python IO further?

All of this is happening on a server that our team uses. Could it be an issue with python's paths for his user session?

For reference, here is the code I'm running in my bash terminal. It's pretty basic:

```
my.name@server:/mnt/data1/my.name/PROJET_X/DATA/BIGWIG$ bamCoverage -p 8 -b /mnt/data1/my.name/PROJET_X/DATA/BAM_sort/G0-G00.Inputs.sorted.bam -o /mnt/data1/my.name/PROJET_X/DATA/BIGWIG/G0-G00.Inputs.RPGC.bw --normalizeUsing RPGC --effectiveGenomeSize 2913022398 -bs 10
The file '/mnt/data1/my.name/PROJET_X/DATA/BAM_sort/G0-G00.Inputs.sorted.bam' does not exist  
my.name@server:/mnt/data1/my.name/PROJET_X/DATA/BIGWIG$ ll /mnt/data1/my.name/PROJET_X/DATA/BAM_sort/G0-G00.Inputs.sorted.bam
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my.name bioinfo 4171366400 juin  22 10:14 /mnt/data1/my.name/PROJET_X/DATA/BAM_sort/G0-G00.Inputs.sorted.bam
```

I have used this line probably 100 times this past year, but now it won't find the file.

I've also tried installing deeptools in my home directory using conda, but that gives the same errors.

EDIT: Apparently, it was just a problem with that one file. bamCoverage will work on other data files. It would be nice if deeptools would tell you that instead of just "file not found"...

Comment: did you try give full path of file?

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan yes, I am giving full path from root

Comment: Does your program still fail to find the file when you execute it with admin rights? Your script may not be allowed to view the content of the directory thus to it it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

> It would be helpful to see what code is being run here - please,
> provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the full output / error, if at all possible.

Right now, I can think of 4 possible solutions to common problems:

- As mentioned in the comments, providing the **full path** might be one solution. You can get the full path by using the `pwd` bash command in the folder where the file is stored and then add the file name at the end of the string.
- Another thing that sometimes helps with relative (local) paths is to **start the path with a "."**, so the path would be something like this: `'./my/dir/data.bam'`.
- Another problem I've encountered (mostly when running things on Windows environments) was that the backslashes had to be used instead: `'\my\dir\data.bam'`
- For the sake of completeness here, I'll mention that especially with beginning programmers, the path is often erroneously provided without commas (to make it a string), but that does not seem to be the case here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've added the line I use for info. As you can see, I'm already using the full path, and I'm using it in a bash shell, not on windows.